# Google maps: ReferenceError - google is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I know that this question was asked multiple times but all other threads doesn't solve my problem.
My problem is: I have angular based application and some of the pages use google maps to display items on the map. Everything was working fine and I didn't change any single line of code and noticed that google maps doesn't work now.

I have google script imported in index file and even not using it in main page:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=ru-RU"></script>
```

Please open this url http://yuppi.com.ua and go to console, wait for 3 seconds and those errors will be displayed.

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined       stat.js
ReferenceError: google is not defined       util.js
ReferenceError: google is not defined       common.js
```

Comment: Did you reference the Maps JS Library? The [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) of the Maps for JS discusses this further. You also may be using [Places JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). Please note that they serve different purpose with Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently those errors occur due to the following code in [script.js file](http://yuppi.com.ua/js/script.js):

```
yuppiApp.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function() {
        Object.keys($window).filter(function(k) {
            return k.indexOf("google") >= 0
        }).forEach(function(key) {
            delete $window[key]
        })
    })
});
```

`delete $window[key]` *deletes* `google` property from `window` object, which in turn *breaks* the loading of Google Maps libraries (`google` is a root namespace of Google Maps API).

I'm not sure why `google` property is getting deleted in your case, but once the specified lines, for example, are commented:

```
yuppiApp.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function() {
        //Object.keys($window).filter(function(k) {
        //    return k.indexOf("google") >= 0
        //}).forEach(function(key) {
        //    delete $window[key]
        //})
    })
});
```

the errors will disappear.

Comment: You right, I removed that function and it works again. This function was added as an attempt to make Google Adsense.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are using google maps before the API is actually loaded. The API is loaded asynchronously so you must be sure to reference it when is loaded. 
To achieve this i know 2 ways:

- you can use the "callback" query param with a global scoped function in which you will init maps elements:

  ```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=ru-RU&callback=initMap"></script>
  ```
- import the Google Loader instead of the API themselves and use it to manage the API load in your JS code:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  ```

  then

  ```
  google.load('maps', '3.exp', {
      other_params: 'sensor=true&language=ru-RU&libraries=places',
      callback: function () {
          // You can now init your maps
      }
  });
  ```